# zsh: return associative array from function

Tags: shell, zsh

How to return assciative arrays from zsh function?

I tried:

```
creatAARR() {
    declare -A AARR=([k1]=2 [k2]=4)
    return $AARR
}
creatAARR
```

But i get error:

```
creatAARR:return:2: too many arguments
```

What is the right way?

**EDIT:**
I captured output to standard output, like how @chepner suggests, but the new variable doesn't seem to behave like an associative array:

```
creatAARR() {
    declare -A AARR=([k1]=2 [k2]=4)
    echo "$AARR"
}
declare -A VALL
NEW_ARR=$(creatAARR)
echo "$NEW_ARR" # 2 4
echo "k1: $NEW_ARR[k1]" # prints just k1:
return
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can't. Shell functions don't return data; they return integer status codes indicating success or failure. You either set a global variable, or you write data to standard output for the caller to capture using `$(...)`.

Comment: Wanting to do that is a big clue that you need to be using a more capable language. I like perl and TCL for when shell doesn't cut it, some people swear by python...

Comment: Yeah was considering that too after attempting to make things work in shell

Comment: @chepner did but the assigned var is not an associative array. updated question.

Comment: @Alterecho : Despite of the (perhaps bad) naming, zsh functions can not **return** anyvalue. They can set the exit code before going back to the caller (which is typically a value from 0 to 127), and the caller can pick up the exit code via the variable `$?`.

Comment: `echo "$NEW_ARR` doesn't write an array value (no such thing exists in shell; array syntax is basically a way of working with multiple variables with similar names); it only writes the values stored in the array. You might be able to do something like `declare -p AARR`, then `x=$(creatAARR); declare -A "NEW_ARR=$x"`, but you are really trying to use very not-shell-like code in a shell.

Comment: The term "function" in shell strays even further from the mathematical definition of a function that it does in other programming languages.

Comment: Yeah true @chepner. Added an answer. It worked for my case.

Comment: @Alterecho Do you think you could Accept my answer?

Answer (score 5):

`return` accepts only an integer and sets the [exit status](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status#Shell_and_scripts) of the function.

Shell commands cannot actually return *values.* If you want pass information to the caller of your function, you have a couple of options available to you:

- You *could* `print` your return value, but this then relies on you to properly format your output and for the caller to correctly parse it. For associative arrays, there are so many ways that this can go wrong; I wouldn’t recommend doing this.
- In Zsh, there is a convention that, to communicate a return value, a function can set `$REPLY` to a scalar value or `$reply` to an array. Unfortunately, there is no convention for passing *associative* arrays. You could, of course, put your key-value pairs simply as elements in the non-associative array `$reply` and then let the caller cast it to or wrap it in an associative array, but this would break the convention and thus might violate your caller's expectations.
- The, in my opinion, best approach is to let the caller specify the name of an associative array, which you can then populate with values. This is also handy when you want to return *multiple* values of any type, since you can let the caller specify multiple variable names.

This last approach you can use as follows:

```bash
% creatAARR() {
  # Restrict $name to function scope.
  local name=$1

  # Delete $1, so $@ becomes the other args.
  shift

  # Assign elements to array. 
  set -A "$name" "$@"
}
% typeset -A AARR=()  # Declare assoc. array
% creatAARR AARR k1 2 k2 4
% typeset -p1 AARR    # Print details
typeset -A AARR=( 
  [k1]=2 
  [k2]=4 
)
```

Comment: Hmmm this sounds a good plan too. WIll test out. Thanks

Comment: @Alterecho Do you think you could Accept my answer?

Comment: An assoc array is basically just a regular array with paired key/values. Therefore, you can use `$reply` for the result array, and then have the caller simply turn it into an assoc array: `typeset -A myaarr=("${reply[@]}")`.

Comment: True, but that’s not the convention in Zsh code. If you look at the functions distributed with Zsh, they pretty much always (no, I haven’t checked exhaustively) use a named parameter for associative arrays, not `$reply`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion anyway!  I’ve updated my answer to include it.

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to get my requirement with this:

```
declare -A VAR1
declare -A VAR2

TYPE_VAR1="TYPE_VAR1"
TYPE_VAR2="TYPE_VAR2"

creatAARR() {
    declare -A AARR=([k1]=2 [k2]=4)
        case $1 in 
    "$TYPE_VAR1")
        set -A VAR1 ${(kv)AARR}
    ;;
    "$TYPE_VAR2")
        set -A VAR2 ${(kv)AARR}
    ;;
    esac
}

creatAARR $TYPE_VAR1 $VAR1

echo "${(kv)VAR1}"

return
```

There may be a better way, but this is what works for me now.
Please feel free to add in your methods.